# how to add mysql.data.dll in asp.net application in remote server

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql, mysql-workbench

while running asp.net application in remote server it is Configuration error

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
  <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>

  </assemblies>
```

> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Answer (score 0):

Put the references assembly in your app /Bin/ 
remove and add reference.. by browsing your `./Bin/mysql.data.dll`
now it will be included in your deployment package.

or consider using [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/) to manage references package.